# How to install Ubuntu on MacBook Air with M1 CPU

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, macbook

I have a Macbook Air with an Apple M1 processor and a 250GB hard drive. I need to install Ubuntu to work with Nemo 2.3.56 and RStudio. What is the best way to use Linux on this laptop: live-USB or HD partitioning?
Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK You can't install Ubuntu on a computer with M1 CPU. Multipass can be an option.

Comment: Multipass or UTM would be the better options, but there will be limitations with some of the hardware. Silly question, but there are MacOS versions for both Nemo and RStudio. Why not use those instead? 

Answer (score 1):

Initial support for the M1 SoC in the Linux kernel was released in version 5.13 on June 27, 2021.[9] The initial versions of the M1 chips contain an architectural defect that permits sandboxed applications to exchange data, violating the security model, an issue that has been described as "mostly harmles" - quoth the Wiki